# How to prove that sin(1/x) is continuous at x≠0

Tags: calculus

Can someone help with the proof that sin(1/x) is continuous for all x≠0.(By the help of epsilon delta defination)

I am sharing what I have tried so far not much though.
I have figured out that modulus value of

sin(1/x)-sin(1/a) is less than modulus value of

(1/x)-(1/a) for all a≠0.From here I am thinking to figure out the required "delta" for the epsilon. But I am unable to do so. Please help me with the solution.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for better visibility.

Answer (score 4):

$|\frac 1 x -\frac  1 a|=\frac {|x-a|} {|a||x|} \leq \frac {|x-a|} {|a|(|a|-|x-a|)} <\frac {|x-a|} {|a|(|a|/2)}$ if $|x-a| <|a|/2$. Hence $|\frac 1 x -\frac  1 a|<\epsilon$ if $|x-a| <|a|/2$ and $|x-a| <\epsilon (|a|^{2} /2)$. Take $\delta \in (0, \min \{|a|/2, \epsilon (|a|^{2} /2)\})$.